# how to optimize a loop with large number

Tags: python, numpy

I have noticed that my program is too slow when I am doing this loop, the fact is that N is a large number (1000000).

```
    start=time.time()
    ipf = 0
    idx = 2
    for iang in xrange(0, N):
        z = np.float64(iang+1)/np.float64(N)
        while scum[ipf+1]<z:
            ipf += 1

        phase_H[idx*5*N+iang*5+0] = np.float32( phase.phase[ipf, 1])
        phase_H[idx*5*N+iang*5+1] = np.float32( phase.phase[ipf, 0])
        phase_H[idx*5*N+iang*5+2] = np.float32( phase.phase[ipf, 2])
        phase_H[idx*5*N+iang*5+3] = np.float32(0)
    print time.time() - start
```

This code takes about 9 seconds. Is there a way to make it faster?

Comment: Try reading this tutorial and apply it http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_fncs_map_filter_reduce.php

Comment: Can you include more of the code? What is `scum`?

Comment: What are `scum`, `phase_H`, `phase.phase`?  Lists or np arrays?  What size (shape if array)?  What `dtype` if array?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code it appears that outer `for` loop runs N times and the inner `while` loop runs over all N elements only once. Which, I think, makes the overall complexity O(2n) which is O(n)

The main cost may be in the conversion to the numpy float, some of which you can pull outside the for loop.

From what is provided I would suggest the following changes:

1. Do conversions outside the for loop

   ```
   converted_N = np.float64(N)
   for iang in xrange(0, N):
         z = np.float64(iang+1)/converted_N
   ```
2. preforming the index calculation once and incrementing this instead of computing it each time

   ```
   base_index = idx*5*N+iang*5
   phase_H[base_index] = np.float32( phase.phase[ipf, 1])
   phase_H[base_index+1] = np.float32( phase.phase[ipf, 0])
   phase_H[base_index+2] = np.float32( phase.phase[ipf, 2])
   ```

You could also further reduce this by moving the `idx*5` outside the while loop.

This will reduce the number of multiplications however these can be considered constant time.

Without any additional information on `scum` a comparison benchmark cannot be run.

Comment: hi @RMcG, thanks for the code , it remains slow , i will try to put this code in fortran and use f2py

Comment: @axeldal yes unfortunately the changes don't really greatly reducing the complexity and will likely be negligible. Best of luck

Comment: That inner loop on `scum` just seems to skip over some values - it just advances the `ipf` index over values that don't matter.  I don't see the point to wrapping  values in `np.float32`.  I never do that in `numpy` code.